# How do I make query as an option in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to set up some Controller in sequelize.
I would like to be able to have different types of queries like for instance:

```
api/hotels
api/hotels/id 
api/hotels?featured=true
api/hotels?featured=true&limit=SOMEVALUE
api/hotels?featured=true&limit=SOMEVALUE&somethingsomething
```

I have managed to have both featured and limit working, however if I dont have limit included none of the rest work properly because the limit will be set to 0 in my backend server :/

Is it possible to make it the various query optional?
I might add this is my first running with sequelize and creating backend at all.

My Controller looks like this:

```
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { min, max, limit, ...others } = req.query;
const parsedLimit = limit ? Number(limit) : null;
    const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
      where: {
        ...others,
        // cheapestPrice: { $gt: min | 1, $lt: max | 100000 },
      },
      limit: Number(parsedLimit),
      [Op.or]: {},
    });
    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I might add that the min and max are supposed to be used in the cheapestPrice, as another query for the api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the various queries optional by conditionally including them in the Sequelize query based on whether the corresponding parameters are present in the request. Something like this should work,

```js
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { min, max, limit, featured, somethingsomething } = req.query;
    const whereClause = {};

    // optional query parameters
    if (min || max) {
      whereClause.cheapestPrice = {
        [Op.gt]: min || 1,
        [Op.lt]: max || 100000,
      };
    }

    if (featured) {
      whereClause.featured = featured;
    }

    // you can add more optional parameters in a similar manner

    const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
      where: whereClause,
      limit: limit ? Number(limit) : null,
      // include other options as needed
    });

    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```